# R: how to impute the NA with the specific date linked with other column

Tags: r, date, na, imputation, date-conversion

I need to impute the NA with the date associated with conversion 1, grouped by each user (USERID).
For the date without a conversion (1) linked with it, impute NULL to it.

Here is the table to show the sample dataset:

| USERID | date | conversion | purchaseTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 1 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2022-03-11 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2022-03-11 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2022-03-11 | 1 | 2022-03-11 |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 | 1 | 2022-03-24 |

Sample code:

```
df <- data.frame(list(USERID = (rep(1, 8) )))
df <-  df %>% add_row(USERID = rep(2, 6))
randomDate <- c("2022-2-5", "2022-2-5", "2022-2-5", "2022-2-5", "2022-2-5", 
"2022-2-6", "2022-2-6", "2022-2-6", "2022-3-11", "2022-3-11", "2022-3-11",
"2022-3-24", "2022-3-24", "2022-3-24") 
df <- df %>% group_by(USERID) %>%
  mutate( purchaseTime = ifelse( conversion == "1", as.Date(date) , NA)  )
df$purchaseTime <- as.Date(df$purchaseTime ,origin="1970-01-01")

df <- df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(randomDate)) 
df <- df %>% mutate(conversion = rep(0, 14)) 
df <- df %>% mutate(PurchaseID = rep(NA, 14)) 
df[5,3]  <- 1
df[14,3]  <- 1
df[11,3]  <- 1
df[5,4]  <- 4
df[14,4]  <- 8
```

**TARGET RESULT:**

| USERID | date | conversion | purchaseTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 1 | 2022-02-05 |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 0 | NULL |
| 2 | 2022-03-11 | 0 | 2022-03-11 |
| 2 | 2022-03-11 | 0 | 2022-03-11 |
| 2 | 2022-03-11 | 1 | 2022-03-11 |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 | 0 | 2022-03-24 |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 | 0 | 2022-03-24 |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 | 1 | 2022-03-24 |

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use tidyr's `fill`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~USERID, ~date, ~conversion, ~purchaseTime,
  1, "2022-02-05", 0, NA,
  1, "2022-02-05", 0, NA,
  1, "2022-02-05", 0, NA,
  1, "2022-02-05", 0, NA,
  1, "2022-02-05", 1, "2022-02-05",
  1, "2022-02-06", 0, NA,
  1, "2022-02-06", 0, NA,
  1, "2022-02-06", 0, NA,
  2, "2022-03-11", 0, NA,
  2, "2022-03-11", 0, NA,
  2, "2022-03-11", 1, "2022-03-11",
  2, "2022-03-24", 0, NA,
  2, "2022-03-24", 0, NA,
  2, "2022-03-24", 1, "2022-03-24"
)

df2 <- df |> 
  group_by(USERID, date) |> 
  fill(purchaseTime, .direction = "updown") |> 
  ungroup() # if needed

df2
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#>    USERID date       conversion purchaseTime
#>     <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>       
#>  1      1 2022-02-05          0 2022-02-05  
#>  2      1 2022-02-05          0 2022-02-05  
#>  3      1 2022-02-05          0 2022-02-05  
#>  4      1 2022-02-05          0 2022-02-05  
#>  5      1 2022-02-05          1 2022-02-05  
#>  6      1 2022-02-06          0 <NA>        
#>  7      1 2022-02-06          0 <NA>        
#>  8      1 2022-02-06          0 <NA>        
#>  9      2 2022-03-11          0 2022-03-11  
#> 10      2 2022-03-11          0 2022-03-11  
#> 11      2 2022-03-11          1 2022-03-11  
#> 12      2 2022-03-24          0 2022-03-24  
#> 13      2 2022-03-24          0 2022-03-24  
#> 14      2 2022-03-24          1 2022-03-24
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>